# Not sure which property should I use for animation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, storyboard, winrt-xaml

I am creating a kiosk app in Windows 8 but it will be used as assigned access app in 8.1. I want to create an animation for ads. The idea of animation is attached as image with this thread. Basically there will be 6-10 images in a L shape (Right side a column & bottom side a row). Now one ad in extreme bottom right corner will be stationary. The ads in column will travers like HTML's marquee and reaches to row at that time the ads in row will travers and reaches to column. In this way the ads will keep of moving in a clock wise pattern. How can I achieve this in my C#/XAML app?

Please not the ads will be never be displayed on top or left. The ad is `<Image />` & source is Internet URLs. All ads are in `ItemsControl`.

[image]

Comment: you could use a [key frame animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742524(v=vs.110).aspx) in which you animate the x and y properties of your elements. in your case you would have to define 4 keyframes: one for entering from the top, one to move to bottom, one to move on the diagonal, one to move outside on the left. then you the repeat the animation from beginning

Comment: I don't have fix number of ads, so what should I do? X & Y will be different for each image I think.

Comment: for the x & y you can just delay the animation. but I don't think you can do what you want only by xaml, I think it would be better to create a new custom user control to do the ad showing job. And use some c# in there

Comment: +1, I was about to just show some `PathListBox` or `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` answer until I realized RT/W8 doesn't have those options, so would be curious enough about this also I may have to throw a bounty at it since I know I'll run into this in the future too. Good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuck, let's start with how much I hate this app already.

**Now to the answer.**

I don't think you really need an animation. You will likely change the ads only every so often. And a simple change in their position and NOT a transition in their position seems adequate.

**Try this:**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad1" Fill="Green" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad2" Fill="IndianRed" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad3" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad4" Fill="DarkRed" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad5" Fill="Pink" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad6" Fill="HotPink" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Ad7" Fill="Purple" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

With this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => Move();
    timer.Start();
}

void Move()
{
    var ads = new Rectangle[] { Ad1, Ad2, Ad3, Ad4, Ad5, Ad6, Ad7 };
    foreach (var item in ads)
    {
        var row = (int)item.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        var col = (int)item.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        if (row == 3)
        {
            if (col == 0)
            {
                row = 0;
                col = 3;
            }
            else
                col--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (row == 2)
            {
                row = 3;
                col = 2;
            }
            else
                row++;
        }
        item.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
        item.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
    }
}
```

And it looks pretty good to me.

**But if you must have animations, try this.**

```
void Move()
{
    var ads = new Rectangle[] { Ad1, Ad2, Ad3, Ad4, Ad5, Ad6, Ad7 };
    foreach (var item in ads)
    {
        var row = (int)item.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        var col = (int)item.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        var x = item.ActualWidth;
        var y = item.ActualHeight;

        // bottom
        if (row == 3)
        {
            // left-last
            if (col == 0)
            {
                row = 0;
                col = 3;
                x = -x;
                y = 0;
            }
            // others
            else
            {
                col--;
                x = -x;
                y = 0;
            }
        }
       // right
       else
        {
           // bottom-last
           if (row == 2)
            {
                row = 3;
                col = 2;
                x = -x;
            }
            else
            {
                row++;
                x = 0;
            }
        }

        var dr = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5));
        var tx = item.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

        var ax = new DoubleAnimation { To = x, Duration = dr };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(ax, tx);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ax, "X");

        var ay = new DoubleAnimation { To = y, Duration = dr };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(ay, tx);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ay, "Y");

        var st = new Storyboard { FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd };
        st.Children.Add(ax);
        st.Children.Add(ay);
        st.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            item.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
            item.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, col);
            st.Stop();
        };
        st.Begin();
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah I expected Jerry will definitely help me. Thanks mate. I like the second solution that's animation. But is it possible to have smooth constant animation? I noticed after completion of story board there's small stop. Is it possible to create like a news ticker kind of animation?

Comment: Again, hate this app. Just adjust the timing so that the animation and the timer.tick are the same. (or near the same, will req some tweaking) Otherwise, might need to look at AnimationAlongPath (or somethign) by Charles Petzold. Not going to be simple.

Comment: Just thought of another way. Since these are just images. You could easily put a scrollviewer vert and horz in the UI and just animate the horizontal offset. It should work, but will require you have 2x as many ads in each viewer, which also means you will have 4x as many ads since they will be in both locations.